# Raspberry 1 Model A RCA hookup to monitor

Tags: video, pi-a

I want to hook my Raspberry Pi 1 Model A up to an older monitor that doesn't support HDMI. From the looks of it, RCA video output *seems* to be a possibility:

[image]

Just a sanity check (because my opportunity to go out to RadioShack and buy the right type of cable is shrinking quickly), can I just take the **white plug** (or yellow?) here:

[image]

...and plug it into the RCA video port on the monitor? Or do I need some type of fancier video cable setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the monitor supports RCA, then any male to male RCA will work. The colours are irrelevant, they're just there so you know which end corresponds to the other end of the cable.

The device outputs video through one line, left speaker through another, and right through another. As long as the receiving device gets the the right signal to the write port, the colours are irrelevant. In theory, if you had a cord that was pink, blue and green it would work too, as long as the pink was plugged into both the Pi's video and the monitor, or the blue was plugged into both, etc. You see where I'm going with this.

Comment: Great, thanks @Nathan Smith (+1) so it *sounds* like my cable should work? Again I ask because I have to leave in about 20 mins to pick up the monitor and if I need to buy a new cable, then I only have one opportunity to get it tonight!

Comment: What's the other end look like? If it's male to male RCA, I'm 95% sure it'll be fine.

Comment: Yep the other end looks identical, so all good?

Comment: Should be. Plug yellow to yellow, let the white hang, you should be fine. Or plug the white to white if you feel like having a minor chuckle. Either should work.